# Por que "decomponível" e não "decomposível" ou "decompível"?

Tags: etimologia, origem, adjetivos

Em aprendizado de máquina, é muito comum os artigos tratarem do termo "**decomposable**", e em mais de uma situação já presenciei pessoas usando o termo original por não saber a versão em português.

Numa rápida busca no dicionário, encontramos que o correto é "**decomponível**", mas existe uma explicação do porquê do surgimento desse inusitado n?

Comment: Porque vêm do latim ***ponere** como pôr, descompor, etc. Ve o n? :)

Comment: Lembrar que também temos "disponível" (de "dispor") talvez ajude a se acostumar com a palavra "decomponível".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É ***decomponível*** basicamente porque se formou a partir do latim ***componĕre***. Isto e tudo o que se segue é baseado no dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002).

O latim tinha todos estes verbos, *ponĕre, componĕre, proponĕre, imponĕre*, etc., que na evolução para o português perderam o -n-, por vezes nasalando a vogal anterior. De maneira que encontramos nos séculos XIII a XV palavras como *põer, compoer, cõpõer, propoer, empoer, trespoẽdo* (“transpondo”), que acabaram por estabilizar em *pôr, compor, impor*, etc.

Mais tarde entraram por via erudita na nossa língua palavras baseadas no verbo latino e que mantiveram o -n-. É o caso do nosso [*decomponível*, atestado em 1802](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9Fvpql-QYN0C&pg=PA35&dq=decompon%C3%ADvel&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjso83GlLziAhXnA2MBHSgpDxAQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=decompon%C3%ADvel&f=false) (minha datação; onde não digo nada, a datação é do Houais), de *componente* (1716), *proponente* (1881), *imponente* (1873), *oponente* (1619), *disponente* (antes de 1600), *disponível* (1873), [*intransponível*](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=340227&pesq=intransponivel&pasta=ano%20185) (1850, minha datação), etc.

É possível que tivesse havido influência do espanhol na formação destas palavras, já que no espanhol estes verbos não perderam o -n- (é *poner, componer*, etc.)