# "Calar" → "calável", "beber" → "bebível"; e para "pôr"?

Tags: morfologia, sufixos

Eu estava procurando se é possível adicionar um sufixo para verbos terminados em *-por* ou o próprio verbo *pôr*, mas eu não encontrei nada.

Quero adicionar um sufixo, como nos exemplos abaixo:

- soltar → solt**ável**;
- matar → mat**ável**;
- saber → sab**ível**;
- beber → beb**ível**;
- sumir → sum**ível**;
- ir → **ível** (não sei se está correto este);
- pôr → ?;
- compor → ?.

Existe algum sufixo assim, para vermos acabados em *-or* ?

Comment: Schilive, espero que tenhas gostado da minha edição da tua pergunta; se não, creio que já sabes, só tens de clicar em "edit" e fazer "rollback" ou alterar à tua vontade. É a tua pergunta. Uma dica: naturalmente eu fico satisfeito quando alguém "desaceita" uma resposta anterior e aceita a minha; para o autor da outra resposta isso não é a surpresa mais agradável do mundo. O que eu faço nas minhas perguntas é votar para cima sempre que uma resposta é razoável e esperar uns dias antes de aceitar uma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para dar mais uns exemplos, os seguintes estão atestados no Priberam:

- Compor → [Componível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/compon%C3%ADvel)
- Decompor → [Decomponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/decompon%C3%ADvel)
- Dispor → [Disponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/dispon%C3%ADvel)
- Impor → [Imponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/impon%C3%ADvel)
- Opor  → [Oponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/opon%C3%ADvel)
- Sobrepor → [Sobreponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Sobrepon%C3%ADvel)
- Superpor → [Superponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/superpon%C3%ADvel)
- Transpor → [Transponível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/transpon%C3%ADvel)

Este vêm listados no Houaiss no verbete *-por*, mas não encontrei com verbete próprio em dicionário nenhum. Mas vêm na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario):

- Expor → Exponível
- Pressupor → Pressuponível
- Propor → Proponível

Este vem também listado no Houaiss no verbete *-por*, mas não encontrei com verbete próprio em dicionário nenhum, nem na [Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario). Encontra-se no entanto em literatura académica no [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk014Fw-3lfSUVDwGHM_ITeOYXDz9mw%3A1586973091734&ei=o0mXXoerLKSHjLsPl4-fuA8&q=contrapon%C3%ADvel&oq=contrapon%C3%ADvel&gs_l=psy-ab.3...8099731.8104042.0.8104456.13.13.0.0.0.0.315.1398.10j2j0j1.13.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.974...0.0.Cp7cOnCm6xo):

- Contrapor → Contraponível

Depois ainda tens adjetivos formados a partir dos anteriores mais o prefixo *in-*:

- Incomponível
- Indecomponível
- Indisponível
- intransponível

Existe, claro, o verbo *indispor*, mas segundo o Houaiss, *indisponível* formou-se a de *in-* + *disponível* e não de *indispor*, o que faz sentido.

Curiosidade: todos estes adjetivos têm um *-n-* — *dispo**n**ível, transpo**n**ível*, etc. — porque são formados a partir do verbo latino, que era *ponere, componere*, etc. Ver [esta pergunta sobre *componível*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6005/por-que-decompon%C3%ADvel-e-n%C3%A3o-decompos%C3%ADvel-ou-decomp%C3%ADvel).

Nota pessoal: eu acho que algumas individualidades são altamente *deponíveis*, mas parece que ainda ninguém inventou a palavra.

Comment: Destituíves, antes fossem...

Comment: @bad_coder, essa palavra também não vem no Priberam, mas *restituível* vem. Diz lá que isto não é panelinha qualquer!

Comment: Tens razão Jacinto. É como o "respondente" (que tem thread aqui)...Vou prestar mais atenção a casos como o desta palavra que indicaste.

Answer (score 3):

- Para *compor* temos [componível](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/compon%C3%ADvel/).
- Para *pôr* (em vista de componível, oponível, disponível), imagino que o candidato seria "ponível". No entanto, parece que não há registro nos dicionários.